# PHP Application needs mbstring library - can't install on EC2

Tags: php

A library on my ecommerce site requires the PHP mbstring library. Seems simple, just run:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

but I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-0-0-0 modules]$ sudo yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.8-1.111.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried to enable the extension, but I get an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/mbstring.so'^
```

I have no idea what to try next...

Comment: Try this yum install php56-mbstring

Comment: `php -v` to know what PHP version you have installed `yum install php56-mbstring` if it is in fact PHP 5.6

Answer (score 1):

You have PHP 5.6 installed in your system, but your `yum` tries to install `mbstring` for PHP 5.3.

You need to install the `mbstring` extension the same way as you have installed PHP 5.6.

Comment: I install it by using  sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd - using this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: how do I get yum to download the same version so that it's compatible..?

Comment: Maybe Amazon's PHP5.6 package reposiry doesn't include `mbstring` extension. Then your only option is to find a repository which includes `mbstring`.